# URL join of two URIs

Tags: python, url, uri

I am trying to join these two URIs

```
from urllib.parse import urljoin    
# baskslash is not a mistake
r = urljoin(r"https:/\\corrlinks.blob.core.windows.net", r"videofaq")  
print(r)
```

I am getting

```
https:///videofaq
```

How can I get

```
https:/\\corrlinks.blob.core.windows.net/videofaq
```

This one would be Ok too:

```
https://corrlinks.blob.core.windows.net/videofaq
```

Note. Browsers handle the link above just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have ended up with

```
url = url.replace("\\" , "/").replace("///", "//")
```

Answer (score 1):

Function interpret slash as baseurl, so you're need to add another one at the end to teach it:

```py
urljoin(r"https:/\\corrlinks.blob.core.windows.net/", "videofaq")
```

Answer (score 0):

python treats backslash(\) as an escape character.

using r'string' goes handy many times.
r just means raw string. This is useful when we want to have a string that contains backslash and don’t want it to be treated as an escape character.
In this case

```
from urllib.parse import urljoin
r = urljoin(r"https://corrlinks.blob.core.windows.net", "videofaq")  
print(r)
# returns https://corrlinks.blob.core.windows.net/videofaq
```

This should do the work.

Comment: I have tried to add "r" in the original code in the question. I get the same result. I will update the question.